# Custom listview adapter, setImageBitmap does not load the bitmap

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

I created my own adapter for a listView(myRSSTitleListAdapter) extended ArrayAdapter of Item  (Item is my entity class) . I overrode the getView method like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
  View view = converView;
  if(view == null) {
    LayoutInflater li =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = li.inflate(layout, null);
  }

  final Item listItem = items[position];

  if(listItem != null) {
    ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageBitmap(ImageTool.loadImage(listItem.getImageURL()));

    HTMLUtilities htmlTool = HTMLUtilities.getInstance();
    TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label);
    title.setText(htmlTool.escapeHTML(listItem.getTitle()));
  }

  return view;
}
```

ImageTool is a class I wrote and `loadImage` returns a bitmap from the url passed to it.
I call myRSSTitleListAdapter in my ListActivity like this :

```
setListAdapter(new myRSSTitleListAdapter(this, R.layout.rss_items, items));
```

items is an array of Item.

`rss_items` is a linearlayout with an imageView and a textView.

For the textView everything is fine and the the setText has an impact on the view I return but the image does not appear (and I am sure the bitmap is here)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in `loadImage`, as your code looks okay.

One of two things should be happening:

1. If `loadImage` is working, the text in your rows should be taking a long time to appear because `getView` won't return until it `loadImage` does.
2. If `loadImage` has an error or is doing work asynchronously, then `getView` will return instantly and only set your text, which is the behavior you're describing.

Loading images asynchronously into an `ImageView` is much trickier than it should be. You might try [DroidFu](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu)'s [WebImageView](https://github.com/kaeppler/droid-fu/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/droidfu/widgets/WebImageView.java) if you can't get it to work.